# XML Generated by DOMDocument with Line Break

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, line-breaks

I am creating XML files with PHP DOMDocument, and these XML files can not contain line breaks.

But when I use the method "**saveXML()**", the generated XML comes with a line break between the definition and the initial tag, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"><infNFe...
```

Can I correct this problem in DOMDocument? Or do I have to do it after I generate the XML?

I'd like to correct this problem to get a result like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><NFe xmlns="...
```

Comment: Why does it matter if there is a line break or not?

Comment: I am using these XML in communication with a webservice. And this webservice does not accept line breaks (though it should).

Comment: @Paulo does the webservice require the xml prolog at all?

Comment: It is a system for electronic invoice from the Brazilian government. For each province there is a webservice. In the province where I am, the webservice has this problem.

Comment: @Paulo yes, but does the webservice require the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` to be send along at all? Would it accept the actual document starting with the root element? Withouth the prolog. Because removing it completely would be possible with DOMDocument.

Comment: To be honest, I'd contact the maintainer of the service and ask them to fix that bug in their implementation

Comment: @Gordon Unfortunately it requires the prolog. This is why I'm almost going crazy. : P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, [`DOMDocument::$preserveWhiteSpace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.preservewhitespace) is true.  Try setting it to false on the document in question, then calling `saveXML` again.  This may have side effects should any whitespace inside the document actually matter.  You should also make sure that [`DOMDocument::$formatOutput`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.formatoutput) is false.

As said by Gordon, though, there is no logical reason whatsoever for the whitespace restriction.  Though seriously, if you don't want any whitespace in there whatsoever, just make sure any CR/LF characters that you want to keep are entity-encoded and then `$nonewlines = preg_replace("/[\r\n]/", '', $xml)` to yank out the newlines that might remain after turning off Preserve and Format.  But again, that's *silly*.

Comment: This wont remove the newline after the prolog IIRC

Comment: Time to break out the regexes!

Comment: I'm already using:

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->preservWhiteSpace = false;
$xmldoc->formatOutput = false;

Comment: So is it just the prolog that has the newline?  If so, you can probably just yank that one newline out of there manually with no side effects.  You haven't indicated that the rest of the document has any formatting or unexpected whitespace.  (A quick glance at the XML spec does not indicate that the newline after the prolog is required, though they always seem to have one in the examples.)

Comment: Thanks @Charles and @Gordon!

You helped me to conclude that the DOMDocument is not able to solve this problem alone.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Charles The rest of the document is ok. :)

Comment: Here's why you might actually not want to have white space in your xml at all. Sometimes it is just easier and more efficient to modify an xml with regular expressions where taking whitespace into account just makes life more complicated