# DOMDocument adds the line break between nodes where there is nothing between the nodes

Tags: php, domdocument

How to prevent *DOMDocument* from adding the line break `\n` after the first paragraph node? When there is space between the nodes the line break is not added.

```
<?php

$text = '<p></p><p></p>';
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text);
$innerHTML = "";
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
    $innerHTML .= $dom->saveHTML($child);
}
echo json_encode($innerHTML);
```

The code above returns:

```
"<p><\/p>\n<p><\/p>"
```

There is the online code there https://3v4l.org/UfZTG

Comment: Don't know why, it it looks like it adds a newline after any paragraph that isn't at the end of the document.

Comment: I recall struggling with this or a similar issue a few years ago. Not sure that I ever solved it, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277120/xml-generated-by-domdocument-with-line-break?rq=1) seems to have some possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today. My use-case seems to have been the same, namely generating an “inner HTML” string from an element. Because I did not want to indiscriminately change or trim white space from nodes, I found a different solution.

Running `DOMDocument::saveHTML` on a `DOMDocumentFragment` (in my testing) never seems to add any extra white space.

Going from your example, you can get the HTML output of the first `P` element without a trailing `\n` by doing:

```php
$frag = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$frag->appendChild(
    $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->cloneNode(true)
);
echo json_encode($dom->saveHTML($frag)); // Renders "<p><\/p>".
```

Note that you must use `DOMNode::cloneNode`, otherwise you are moving the element into the `DOMDocumentFragment` and remove it from its original place.

If you are looking for an inner HTML function, the following should work. It will move all the child nodes of an element into a `DOMDocumentFragment`, then get the HTML value, and put the nodes back where they belong. This means we aren’t cloning notes, nor leaving the tree changed when we are done.

```php
function innerHTML(\DOMElement $element): string
{
    $fragment = $element->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
    while ($element->hasChildNodes()) {
        $fragment->appendChild($element->firstChild);
    }
    $html = $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($fragment);
    $element->appendChild($fragment);
    return $html;
}
```